# A thread-safe WebDriver pool to submit browsing jobs to

Tags: python, python-3.x, selenium, webdriver

For a project, I need to make use of Selenium WebDrivers, and since they're so expensive to start, I decided to write a pool to manage them.

```
with driver_pool.FirefoxWebDriverPool(5) as d_pool:
    # Sequentially visit a page 1000 times
    for _ in range(1000):
        # Don't actually run this. I accidentally go myself rate-limited by SO for doing this.
        d_pool.run_job(lambda driver: driver.get("http://www.stackoverflow.com"))
```

I realized after writing this that really, it could be generalized to handle arbitrary objects, but for the sake of keeping it simple, I'm going to keep it as is. I could also generalize it to handle all WebDrivers, but drivers have slightly different interfaces, and I wanted to allow going into headless mode, so again, to keep it simple, I'm sticking with Firefox.

I've never written an object pool before, and I haven't written thread-safe code meant for a multi-threaded environment in awhile. I'd like tips on how this can be cleaned up. I'm making use of multiple primitives, so if I'd like to know if it can be simplified. `_pending_lock` and `_n_pending` are being used because I realized while writing `terminate` that I had no way of knowing if there are any jobs outstanding that may cause a driver to get missed while terminating.

The solution I went for is to count how many threads are currently stuck waiting inside the method. If a job finishes and it was the last job, it signals an `Event` (`_can_terminate`) that it's safe to terminate. If another job is submitted, the event is cleared to indicate that it's no longer safe. When `terminate` is called, it will prevent any new jobs from being submitted, `wait` for the all-clear, then pop drivers while calling `quit` on them. My main concern is preventing resource leakage because of their potential to bog down my system if leaked repeatedly.

Any tips at all would be appreciated.

```
from __future__ import annotations
from typing import Callable, Optional, TypeVar
from threading import Lock, Event
import queue

from selenium.webdriver import Firefox
from selenium.webdriver.firefox.options import Options

T = TypeVar("T")

class FirefoxWebDriverPool:
    def __init__(self, max_drivers: int, headless: bool = True):
        self._available_drivers = queue.Queue(maxsize=max_drivers)
        self._terminating = False
        self._can_terminate = Event()

        self._pending_lock = Lock()  # TODO: Find a clean way of using Queue.qsize instead
        self._n_pending = 0

        options = Options()
        options.headless = headless

        for _ in range(max_drivers):
            self._available_drivers.put(Firefox(options=options))

    def run_job(self, job: Callable[[Firefox], T]) -> Optional[T]:
        """Runs a job in a browser pool.
        Will return the result of the job if the job succeeded, or None if the job failed
        due to termination of the pool being in progress."""
        driver = None
        try:
            with self._pending_lock:
                if self._terminating:
                    return None
                else:
                    self._n_pending += 1
                    self._can_terminate.clear()

            driver = self._available_drivers.get()
            return job(driver)
        finally:
            # Should never be None, but could theoretically be if a lock throws due to a bug in our logic.
            if driver is not None:
                self._available_drivers.put(driver)  # Should not be possible to be full.
            with self._pending_lock:
                self._n_pending -= 1
                if self._n_pending == 0:
                    self._can_terminate.set()

    def terminate(self) -> None:
        self._terminating = True
        self._can_terminate.wait()

        while self._available_drivers.qsize() > 0:
            driver: Firefox = self._available_drivers.get()
            driver.quit()

    def __enter__(self) -> FirefoxWebDriverPool:
        return self

    def __exit__(self, *_) -> None:
        self.terminate()
```